Do the lyrics of 'more than words' contain a Grammar fault?
I have a question about the song 'more than words' from Extreme.

Saying I love you, is not the words I want to hear from you.

Shouldn't it be 'are not the words'?

Is "saying" singular or plural?

'Saying' here is the verb / a verby (depending on analysis chosen) ing-form and refers to the uttering not the utterance.
Compare the equally unacceptable 'Writing a letter is not the information required.'

Like "(this) is not the (thing) I want to hear from you". Thanks!
